# Python sending email with signature in outlook

Tags: python, outlook, com, outlook-redemption

I'm trying to send email with a default outlook signature using win32com in python. 
    People mentioned Redemption has RDOsession to add signature by using ApplyTO().
    But I don't know how to use Redemption, or RDOsession or ApplyTO() into my code.

```
import win32com.client as win32

outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
session = win32.Dispatch('Redemption.RDOsession') #gives me an error message

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'myemail@gmail.com'
mail.Subject = 'test subject'
mail.Body = 'test body'

session.ApplyTo() # not sure if it can be used like this
mail.Send()
```

I'm new to COM or whatever library Redemption is.
    Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you download Redemption from http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/download.htm and install the ddl with the right bitness using regvr32.exe?

Comment: Is your issue sending an email? Sending an email with a signature? Have you read the documentation for Redemption at http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm?

Comment: I downloaded redemption and installed it on my computer, but I don't know how to use it.